# Trying to filter database on GraphQL

Tags: filter, graphql

I'm using a API from objkt.com (you can see the graphiQl here https://public-api-v3-20221206.objkt.com/explore/), and I'm trying to do some searches.
Filtering by token like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  token(
    where: {creators: {creator_address: {_eq: "tz1W5C3scSjmfzgxkkXgQeRUrLoHWakHhET1"}}, holders: {holder_address: {}}}
  ) {
    pk
    holders {
      holder_address
    }
  }
}
```

One of results will be this:

```
"token": [
  {
    "pk": 597839,
    "holders": [
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1W5C3scSjmfzgxkkXgQeRUrLoHWakHhET1"
      },
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to filter the tokens that have this two address above, the only I search for, and this one: "tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX".

Other results can be like this (I don't want like this):

```
  {
    "pk": 62751145,
    "holders": [
      {
        "holder_address": "tz2DYZ4oA2Nc1g4FqVoA7JATa1GvikkFDUUU"
      },
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1W5C3scSjmfzgxkkXgQeRUrLoHWakHhET1"
      },
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1V1JYCMfhCvKuHUE2p5sFjUexLzVcmPNZk"
      },
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1TG817WE91BjfDgxDf4oDvQ7GNRYSR3C1J"
      },
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1eUq1U9Xy3AEesTwTVdhC6pMArew5Z3zbe"
      },
      {
        "holder_address": "tz1TBJCAY6vDzubGkHWFXrtqWHXW9GE6mSnF"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried to use the operators like _eq and _in. If I filter by the second address (tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX) will filter some tokens, but I want to filter the tokens that have both address, so I do _and operator and again, put the other address in _eq or _in, but the results are the same and I can't figure out how to filter only the two addresses.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you are asking, or what your desired behaviour is. Can you show your current solution and how the output of this differs from what you would like to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to filter on both the creator and holder addresses. It's not quite clear how to use the `_or` in this api but `_in` appears to work quite well.

Please try:

```
query MyQuery {
  token(
    where: {
      creators: {
        creator_address: {
          _eq: "tz1W5C3scSjmfzgxkkXgQeRUrLoHWakHhET1"
        }
      },
      holders: {
        holder_address: {
          _in: ["tz1W5C3scSjmfzgxkkXgQeRUrLoHWakHhET1","tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX"]
        }
      }
    }
  ) {
    pk
    holders {
      holder_address
    }
  }
}
```

However the filter on `holder_address` only guarantees that one of the results is in the list of two addresses. Other addresses might also appear  in the output. It's unclear how these might be filtered out if at all.